# 301 redirect with htaccess from Tumblr to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, tumblr

I'm quite new with htaccess, so I'd require some light here.

I set a new site with Wordpress and want to redirect my old Tumblr posts to the ones I imported to Wordpress.

Domain structure is as follows:

Old Tumblr: tumblr.domain.com

New Wordpress: www.domain.com

And the post structure is:

Old Tumblr: tumblr.domain.com/post/numberID/post-title

New Wordpress: www.domain.com/post-title

I made my research and I don't know why, by some reason I'm just having 404.

What I thought was my best bet was this:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tumblr.domain.com/post/(.*?)/(.*?)$

RewriteRule http://www.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]`

But doesn't work, I only have a 404.

Note: I also see my home (www.domain.com) when entering tumblr.domain.com

Any help would be very apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, solved myself, I had to rebuild my htaccess due some addiotional problems I found. 
Anyway, for anyone trying to redirect tumblr posts from a subdomain to it's main domain, this is how I made it:

First, 301 from subdomain to domain:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tumblr\.domain\.com  [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

And then, 301 from tumblr posts to imported posts:

`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+).(.*?)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [L,R=301]`

For some cases, I renamed some posts in my new site, so it won't work for those. I had to redirect manually for those posts, so I had to add the following line after the lines above:

`RewriteRule ^old-post-title http://www.domain.com/new-post-title/ [R=301,L]`

Hope this works for someone in the same situation.